# Paste command using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, clipboard, sikuli

I'm using Python 2.7 and Selenium 2-44-0 on Windows 7.  I'm looking for a quicker way of inputting text than using send_keys.  Send_keys will print 1 letter at a time (which better imitates an actual user).  I would like a way to print all of them out at once, as if the content was pasted.

For example, Sikuli has the following functionality:

```
paste("this will all populate the field at the same time")
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to write a method in Python that will have the same result.  So, instead of:

```
el.send_keys("this will do 1 letter at a time")
```

Have something like

```
el.paste_keys("this will do the entire line at once")
```

Since the above command would require adding code to selenium functionality, it would prob make more sense to have a python method.  Maybe something along the lines of:

```
def paste_keys(self, xpath, text):
    os.environ['CLIPBOARD'] = text
    el = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    el.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

Using that environmental variable doesn't actually act as a 'copy', though, and I don't know how to set the clipboard from the code level without downloading 3rd party software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def paste_keys(self, xpath, text):
    os.system("echo %s| clip" % text.strip())
    el = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    el.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

There cannot be a space after %s, for it will add that to the copied text.

Comment: what about using the `strip()` method on the text?  split isn't what you want.

Comment: typo; I meant to put strip.  However, it still keeps the space.  It seems to be added AFTER going to the clipboard, so I'd need a way of setting the clipboard value to a variable or something so I can edit it from there

Comment: aha! figured it out.  the line "echo %s | clip" is recognizing the space in between the %s and | as part of the text; I removed that, and there's no longer a space

Comment: Great. But Getting error: `NameError: name 'Keys' is not defined`

Comment: @AdilSaju You might want to import Keys first `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

Comment: @user2869231 what should i enter for "self" and "text" while calling the function. If just enter the xpath , i get an error saying that positional arguments are missing.If i simply remove text and self , i get another error saying "text" not defined