# Testing Copying/Pasting with RobotFramework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I create some custom copying functionality for my web application that I want to test. I can't find any Keywords for copying or pasting [in the documentation](https://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.6.1) though. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question - RobotFramework will only manage your testing, it won't test your website? If you're asking how to copy and paste using selenium and python - I've provided an answer. Otherwise please edit your question to be more clear, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this functionality is not available and issue for that is open for more then 2 years already. https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/498

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use the following code for copy paste in Robot Framework
1.Install clipboard library using command in CMD : pip install clipboard
2.use code:  
          Copy To Clipboard     ${TextToCopy}       
          Click Element         ${TargetLocator}    
          Press Key             ${TargetLocator}       \\22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium2Library that has a keyword name `Press Key` then we could get the values from ascii table such as [ASCII Table](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html)

We can see that ctrl+A hex value is 01 -  we need to hit that to highlight the text.

You could try something like this

```
Copy Text and Paste Text
    [Documentation] 
    ...    CTRL-A -> 1
    ...    Copy-> 03
    ...    Paste -> 16
    Press Key    ${seleniumLocator}    \1    #Highlight the text Ctrl+ A
    Press Key    ${seleniumLocator}    \03    #Copy Text Ctrl + c
    Press Key    ${Some_Other_Locator}   \16  # Paste Text Ctrl+ v
```

Answer (score 0):

For copying and pasting using Selenium + python (using keyboard shortcuts):

[Performing-a-copy-and-paste-with-selenium-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750447/performing-a-copy-and-paste-with-selenium-2)

You can also create a method to re-use (e.g. using RobotFramework):

[Paste command using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637931/paste-command-using-selenium)

You will need to first import the [selenium2 library for RobotFramework](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library).

Comment: You are mixing Robot Framework and Selenium library in Python itself. Can you explain the example more specifically please? I can not understand, how you can directly call Selenium functions from Robot Framework.

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was to point out that you can script copy/paste in Selenium+Python (as an example). I was not aware RobotFramework had a limitation in regarding to implementing that. From what I can see from the link you pasted there's a hack that still works - https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/275#issuecomment-35382111

Answer (score 0):

I have been using RFW for a while now. I've **never heard** of copy/paste as you mentioned.

Thus, the only way would be custom your own keywords based on python libraries.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the OS library of Robot Framework
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Copy%20File