# Python Selenium Webdriver paste from clipboard

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, clipboard, paste

We have an internal website that has different users with different permissions and passwords and each has a button that copies the password to the clipboard so we can paste it into the login screen. Each button has an ID of AuserPwd, Buserpwed, Cuserpwd... I know how to get Selenium (Python) to click on that button, so that the password is in my clipboard, but how can I paste it into a different url password field. 
Basically, can I pass my clipboard to a variable and paste that variable into a field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste command using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637931/paste-command-using-selenium)

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple workaround using [xsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel)

```
    import subprocess
    print(subprocess.check_output(["xsel"])
```

Above code will give you the clipboard copied data,now using selenium just paste the data into the desired page.